# Using drop down lists, count formula, and conditional formatting

Tags: microsoft-excel

I am making a rota that has a crew call on it. One day it might need 3 people in a role, but then the next day it only needs one.

Basically, I'd like to be able to enter a number at the top of a day (Example Stage Crew: 3) and then on the rota below, using drop down lists, assign people to that role, and then the number entered above (3) turn green when the drop down list count on those days equals 3, if that makes sense?

I have the drop downs working, its just.. how do I get the numbers as the top to reference a value in the cell and then count how many times it occurs

Example of Sheet

https://i.stack.imgur.com/OnsfS.png

Thanks!

Comment: COUNTIF or COUNTIFS?

Comment: Welcome to Super User!   Please [Edit] your question to include sample data as text and your expected result.  Convert copied cells/tables from Sheets to [proper markdown format](https://superuser.com/editing-help#tables). Tools like the [Markdown Table Generator](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables) can make this easier.  Include relevant formulas describing what did/didn't work including any errors you encountered.

Comment: Another thing that might help people make suggestion is in column D, =FORMULATEXT point it to the related cell in the row with formula so we can see what you're up to.